# Armor penalty in song of ice and fire

Tags: armor, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

I can't seem to find the effects of the armor penalty in the book. Can anyone tell me what the armor penalty penalizes?

Comment: Downvoted for "read the book to me". The answer is clearly presented in the book under the appropriate heading (as demonstrated by my answer) and requires no expert knowledge to find. Please show some research effort before asking here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a penalty on combat defense and agility tests. The formula for combat defense is repeated several times through the rules, and is as follows:

> Combat Defense = Agility + Awareness + Defensive Bonus (from shields or parrying weapons) - Armor Penalty

The penalty on agility tests is mentioned under the **Armor Penalty** heading on page 150:

> All forms of armor impose a penalty that you apply to all results of your Agility tests (including passive tests) and to your Combat Defense.